# django accessing request.post data

Tags: django

I've assigned form to be request.POST and request.FILES below

But how then do I access the field values. E.g. in the request.post, we have a field called title, how do I get to it?

THanks

```
form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    i=0
    title = request.GET.get('title')
    version = request.GET.get('version')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you already used `form.is_valid()`, I will recommend using `cleaned_data` to retrieve the information.

For example:

```py
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = request.POST.copy()
```

Then you can use data to access the user's submitted data.

To get data from a specific field, use what is set in the name attribute to call the field. This is not always the same as id.
Use .get() to access the field, because if the field is left empty in the form, it will not be in data, and None will be returned.